# Lavaan "fitmeasures" and fit.measures command in R

Tags: r, summary, r-lavaan, sem

I tried running CFA using lavaan. CFA command runs just fine. summary command with "fit.measures = FALSE " runs fine. But summary command with "fit.measures = TRUE" just makes the console busy without producing anything as in the attached image. It has happened recently.
[image screenshots of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdVmb.png) I googled about i got no answer on the issue. I work with lavaan regularly, I have never encountered this issue before. Everytime I apply "fit.measures" to any project it takes a lot of time to process these days. Same size for the code attached is just 300. It took almost two hours to excecute and produce output for "fitMeasures(fit2, c("chisq", "df", "pvalue", "cfi", "tli", "rmsea"))" today.

```
fit2<- cfa(model=model,
           data=data, 
           missing = "FIML", 
           estimator="ML",
           std.lv=TRUE,
           meanstructure=TRUE)
fitMeasures(fit2, c("chisq", "df", "pvalue", "cfi", "tli", "rmsea"))
summary(fit2,              # <- our fit object from cfa()
        fit.measures=TRUE, # <- get our model fit information
        standardized=T)
```

Comment: What's your sample size? How long are you waiting? Does it work with a smaller sample, or with different data? [Also, it's easier for readers if you paste the text into the question, instead of adding an image.]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it was solved by installing an older version of lavaan (version 0.6-12):

```
library(remotes)
install_version("lavaan","0.6-12")
```